# How do I use RS256 algorithm with RSACryptoServiceProvider

Tags: c#, .net, rsa

According to [microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.-ctor?view=netcore-3.1) the constructor is of the form:

```
public RSACryptoServiceProvider (int dwKeySize);
```

*Initializes a new instance of the RSACryptoServiceProvider class with a random key pair of the specified key size. dwKeySize = The size of the key to use in bits.*

So if I want to use RS256 does this mean I need to pass in the argument of 2048?

I'm a little confused because the default constructor (i.e. no arguments passed) creates a 1024-bit key. I'm not sure why they would use 1024.

Comment: If you plan to generate new public/private key pair - then yes, you have to pass 2048 to constructor. If you plan to import existing key - it doesn't matter what value do you pass to constructor.

Comment: `RS256` typically refers to JWT tokens signature methods, which are `RSA` + `SHA256` meaning that a SHA256 hash of the payload is signed using RSA. The RSA itself is not 'X bytes' but the keysize will dictate the maximum size of data that can be signed with RSA meaning you will need at least a 2048 key for `RS256`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comments I have a better understanding now. The key size isn't actually the algorithm used. The key size determines how easy it is to crack. 2048 is the recommended min key size when using RS256 (but theoretically you could use a different size). If using Jose JWT library, you will state what the algorithm used is.

```
var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048); //Create keys with size 2048 bits
string token=Jose.JWT.Encode(payload, rsa, JwsAlgorithm.RS256); //Here we state the algo is RS256
```